# ASP.NET Web Service DTO Properties vs Public Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a web service that will return a List where Person is a DTO. Is there any reason I shouldn't define Person like:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name;
    public string Email;
}
```

instead of

```
public class Person {
    private string _name;
    public string Name {
      get {
       return _name;
      }
      set {
       _name = value;
      }
   }
}
```

The second version is more verbose, and I can't see any reason public instance variables could be a problem here. Any reason it could be?

Answer (score 2):

Properties are preferred over fields to support

- binding; fields cannot be bound
- polymorphism; you can't do `public virtual string Name;`

You can use automatic properties to reduce the verbosity

```
public class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it wasn't defined which service technology though - some proxy classes are generated as fields, not properties.

Answer (score 1):

In general - this is a design decision - see: http://forums.asp.net/t/1233827.aspx
But the DTO implementation is slightly different. Since this is just a DTO and there is no behavior with no set/get property specific implementation the usage you could just as well use the less verbose method. Any implementation change would not require client recompiles since they will be serialized the same way in either case via a service, so your smaller implementation is fine.

Fyi though - if the client is going to use these classes for databinding then they need to be properties in the class. Fields won't be bound.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the other answers, properties allow for validation to be ran when the property is read from or written to.  That would take more work to do when using fields.